# Factory y seeds en laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Saludos chicos, quiero hacer lo siguiente:

- Relacionar usuarios con perfiles
- Relacionar posts a los usuarios
- Relacionar categorias a los posts

He creado 4 tablas `Usuarios`, `Perfiles`, `Posts` y `Categorias`

Y quiero llenar la base de datos usando usando el factory de laravel 5 y que estos datos ya esten relacionados unos con el otro!! y una breve documentacion del código,

> He visto algo en la documentación, pero no lo tengo bien claro.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Muestrános algo de código, algún intento, por pequeño que sea.

Comment: No creo que se necesite codigo para responder esta preguta. Solo quiero tener claro como usar los factorys para relacionar los registros al usar el seed...

Comment: Una búsqueda rápida en Google de "ejemplo factory seeds laravel" arroja como primer resultado un enlace a un sitio web muy conocido, en español: https://styde.net/model-factories-en-laravel-5-1/

Comment: Gracias por responder @chaz, viendo el post, efectivamente te dice como usar el seed y los factories, pero no me dice como relacionar los datos en el seed con otra tabla creada. y eso es lo que busco, que el factory al ejecutarse ponga datos que exista en otra tabla que en mi caso seria el id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He solucionado mi problema. Se que existe otro método, pero este de momento me funcionó.

Se que pedí la relacion con varias tablas, pero en este caso aplica igual uno como para con todos.

En la función `run` de `DatabaseSeeder.php` coloqué esto

```
$this->call(ProfilesTableSeeder::class);
$this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
```

> Importante llamar primero el seed de los perfiles y despues el de los usuarios ya que no puede existir un usuario sin perfil

en `UsersTableSeeder` use el siguiente `factory`

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {

    $p = []; // Array para guardar los id's de los perfiles
    $profiles = App\Profile::get(['id']); // Consulta de los Perfiles (Si no colocamos el Seed de perfiles primero, esta linea traera datos vacios ya que no se han creado los perfiles)
    foreach ($profiles as $k => $v) {
        $p[] = $v->id; // añadimos el valor al array
    }
    return [
        /*
         * El método `randomElement` recibe por parametro un array y escoje un valor aleatorio 
         */
        'profile_id' => $faker->randomElement($p)
    ];
});
```